# image not properly placed on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/YXxsH/5/

Above jsfiddle drop an image to canvas
problem is when i put the code in website
and drop the image it is place on far right side rather then where i drop it

```
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("graphCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.lineWidth = 2;
}
var pos;
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function get_pos(ev){
    pos = [ev.pageX, ev.pageY];
}
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var offset = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

    var img = canvas = document.getElementById("img1");
    var dx = pos[0] - img.offsetLeft;
    var dy = pos[1] - img.offsetTop;
 document.getElementById("graphCanvas").getContext("2d").drawImage(document.getElementById(data), ev.pageX - dx, ev.pageY - dy);
}
```

Comment: Works well on Chrome 31 XP. What browser are you testing on?

Comment: it works as it is now
but when i placed in on canvas that is on relative area of webpage it doesnt works as suck

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the relative position of the canvas element as well.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/FgM48/

```
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
var canvas = document.getElementById("graphCanvas");
var dx = pos[0] - (img.offsetLeft - canvas.offsetLeft);
var dy = pos[1] - (img.offsetTop - canvas.offsetTop);
```